# I am confused in creating attribute and in creating attribute set. Kindly help me

Tags: magento-1.9, category

If there is two category for example say category A and category B and they are attributes with name size and color and i wanted to add color in cat-A as well as cat-B but " In filters of cat-A it should show " Delight Colors " and in cat-B it should show " Beautiful Colors " " but the colors remains the same only the name in the header changes.

So will i have to add different attribute for both categories A and B. Like Beautiful colors attribute for category A and Delight colors attribute for category B OR Question: Should i only add colors as the main category.?
Answer: If yes,than how to assign the name delight and beautiful to colors.

KINDLY CHECK THE IMAGE
[![3 Different categories with different name but all the colors are same
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywiUt.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywiUt.jpg)

3 Different categories with different name but all the colors are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use one color but where your color showing code use condition with category id if category A then display "Delight Colors" and category B " Beautiful Colors "

like you want to display different title based on category like put this condition

```
category A ID ->3  
category B ID ->5
category c ID ->6
```

So in design check like below code

```
if($categoryid == 3){
 echo 'saree color';
}else if($categoryid == 5) {
  echo 'Kurta color';
}else if($categoryid == 5) {
  echo 'Lehenga color';
}
```

Please use this code and if not understand please add your code i will explain where you need to change.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and be more specific i am unable to get you,